# how to sort array os objects which is alphanumeric

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort array as shown  of objects which contains alphanumeric value

```
[
{ bayid="A1",  status=0}, 
{ bayid="A7",  status=0}, 
{ bayid="A6",  status=0}, 
{ bayid="A5",  status=0}
]
```

i am using the .sort method which is shown below

```
var sortedArray = modifiedStatusArray.sort(function(a, b) {
                return +b.bayid > +a.bayid;
            });
```

but not sure how to sort and get the output as shown below

```
[

{ bayid="A7",  status=0}, 
{ bayid="A6",  status=0}, 
{ bayid="A5",  status=0},
{ bayid="A1",  status=0}
]
```

please help

Comment: That sort method won't work for any data, let alone alphanumeric data. A sort callback isn't supposed to return a boolean.

Comment: Try using just `.sort(function(a,b){ return b.bayid.match(/\d+/) - a.bayid.match(/\d+/) })`

Answer (score 4):

I notice that you have a problem with your objects, the definition of you variable should be as follows:

```
var data = [
    { bayid: "A1",  status: 0}, 
    { bayid: "A7",  status: 0}, 
    { bayid: "A6",  status: 0},
    { bayid: "A5",  status: 0}
];
```

You can use the sort function:

```
var sorted = data.sort(function(a, b){
    if( a.bayid === b.bayid ){
      return 0;
    } else if ( a.bayid < b.bayid ) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return -1;
    }
});
console.log( sorted );
```

The `sort` function takes a function as an argument, that function behaves as a comparison function (optional argument), that sort the values of the array based on the returned value of the function.

From the spec:

> The array elements are sorted according to the return value of the compare function

If the returned value is:

- less than 0, sort a to a lower index than b.
- 0 (equal to zero), leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other.
- greater than 0, sort b to a lower index than a.

More information from [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

There is [a very similar question on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript) as well it might be helpful, if you search on the site before creating a new question.

Comment: According to W3, Array.sort expects an integer return value (-1, 0, 1), not a boolean.

Comment: your order is `[ { bayid: 'A1', status: 0 },
  { bayid: 'A5', status: 0 },
  { bayid: 'A6', status: 0 },
  { bayid: 'A7', status: 0 } ]`

Answer (score 1):

Your sort function should return `1`, `-1` or `0`

```
var sortedArray = modifiedStatusArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.bayid < b.bayid ? 1 : a.bayid > b.bayid ? -1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: I think the sorting might be backwards here. If a < b then it should return negative.

Comment: @Comptonburger try it yourself, it's working, `a < b` should return `1`